# is it possible to send email with javascript on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to make an email sent to the email address in the input when button is clicked? form like:

```
<form action="/" method="post" name="form" target="_blank">
    <h3><span>Subscribe to Newsletter</span></h3>
    <p class="email_first">
        <label for="email">Your Email</label>
        <input id="EMAIL" class="email" type="email" name="EMAIL" value="Your Email Address:" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p class="submit"><button type="submit">Send</button></p>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: using the email from the input in the form

Comment: You can have it open a "mailto:" URI, and it will launch the mail client.

Comment: Assuming, of course, the user _has_ a mail client.  Or at least one the browser would know about.  That's a pretty big assumption.  To consistently work across all users it's recommended to handle this sort of thing server-side instead of client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is client side, therefore you can't directly call any kind of email sending services. If you use Ajax and have it call on a PHP/JSP page, then it's possible, but with pure Javascript it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an email directly with java script.But, you can open the default mail client (say Outlook) from Java Script.

```
window.open('mailto:emailt@email.com');
```

Or you can ask your server to do the Job!

Comment: In some browsers using `window.open()` like this can cause a blank new browser window/tab to open too.

Comment: Yes. That's taken. The best would be to be to let the server do it. Because, we can't simply assume that an email client will be configured in every machine